# Exploring a Novel Pattern in Exponential Number Sequences and Their Relation to Factorials

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, number-theory

Introduction

I've been exploring a concept in mathematics that I've termed "string math," which involves examining patterns in exponential number sequences and their intriguing connection to factorial numbers. This exploration was initially inspired by exploring Fermat's Last Theorem and my curiosity about exponential values and correlated values.

Concept Description, Base Strings:

The core idea of "string math" is based on the traditional number line, represented as a sequence of numbers raised to a power. I denote these sequences as "Base Strings" ($Bn$), where '$n$' represents the exponent. For example:

```
B1=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,…] (numbers raised to the 1st power)
B2=[0,1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64,81,…] (squares of numbers)
...And so on for higher powers.
```

Substrings and Root Strings:

I've examined that by taking the differences of sequential values in these base strings, we can form "Substrings"($nSn$). Continuing this process, we eventually reach a "Root String" ($Rn$), which is a sequence of repeating integers. This is what the entire string "tree" would look like for $B3$(cubed numbers)

```
 [0,1,8,27,64,125,216,343,512,729,1000,…]-B3(cubed numbers, base string)
 [1,7,19,37,61,91,127,169,217,271,…]-1S3(first substring of B3)
 [6,12,18,24,30,36,42,48,54,…]-2S3(second substring of B3)
 [6,6,6,6,6,6,6,…]-3S3(third substring of B3, also root string or R3)
```

For any $Bn$, the root string always occurs on the nth string of the tree. So, for $B5$, the fifth substring($5S5$) is the root string, a string of repeating integers.

Connection to Factorials:

Interestingly, the constant value in each root string($Rn$) for any base string($Bn$) appears to be the factorial of '$n$' ($n!$). For example, the root string for $B3$ (cubed numbers) is a constant sequence of 6s, which is $3!$ that occurs on the 3rd substring ($3S3$). We can work out any string tree to see this pattern is consistent. The root string for $B7$(numbers raised to 7th power) occurs on the 7th string($7S7$) and is a repeating series of $7!$. Likewise the root string for, say, $B1241$ (numbers raised to the 1,241st power) would occur on the 1,241st string($1241S1241$) and would be a repeated series of $1241!$.

Questions:

1: Are there known mathematical principles or theories that describe or relate to the patterns I've observed in these sequences?

2: Could this method of generating sequences from exponentials and their connection to factorials have implications or applications in other areas of mathematics?

3: I am seeking feedback on the novelty and potential significance of this. Are there avenues in mathematics where this perspective could provide new insights?

Closing:

I appreciate any insights or guidance you can provide. My background is not in formal mathematics, so this exploration is quite new to me, and I'm eager to learn from the community's expertise. I have generated the string "trees" for all base strings from B1 thru B10 and each holds this pattern. I understand that there is nothing novel about factorials and that using strings or integer series is nothing new either, but this key little detail seems intriguing to me. It also seems to me that there could be additional correlations found between trees from base strings and within the substrings between $Bn$ and $Rn$.

Thank you for your time and consideration.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use MathJax to format your posts.

Comment: Not sure what the question is.  If $A=\{a_n\}$ is an sequence defined by a polynomial (that is, $a_n=p(n)$ for some polynomial $p$), then taking successive differences of $A$ always returns a constant eventually. And conversely....if taking successive differences yields a constant eventually, then you must have started with a polynomial sequence.  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Yes, in the sense that my starting strings are a list of integers raised to a power. I've been exploring sequences where each term is an exponentiation of its position, like $B_n = {n^k}$ for some integer $k$. I've noticed that after $k$ iterations of substrings, the resulting sequence becomes constant and its value is $n!$. 
The strings between the base string and the constant string of $n!$ also are interesting and I think correlations between substrings of different $Bn$ trees exist. I was curious if this is a known feature of exponentiation of integers.

Comment: @Robin Thank you for the heads up, I just figured out how to comply with this request and have edited it accordingly. Feel free to let me know if there is additional steps I can take to correctly use this forum and features!

Comment: Notice that taking the difference is a discrete version of the derivative, and that ${d^n\over x^n} x^n=n!$